# Error while calculating correlations between columns of a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to use a while loop to go through my columns and calculate the correlations between one fixed column and the rest.

```
i = 1
while i < 51:
    feature = 'mean(f{0})-PR'.format(str(i))
    feature_list.append(feature)
    corr = df['mean(f19)-PR'].corr(df[feature])
    i += 1
```

This gives me an Error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you have some columns with object datatype.

Correlation can't be used with nominal/categorical features.

If you want to achieve that, you can use another library called Predictive Power Score https://github.com/8080labs/ppscore